# Refresh Current Fragment (ListView Data) remaining in the same activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

Calling a `Fragment` from an `Activity`, I am displaying a `ListView` with two `Buttons`. When I click on a `menu_item` (i.e. Show Online), i am updating the data and so the `ListView`. Now I need to reflect the updated data. How can i refresh the `Fragment` after i click Show Online. Till now, I have used the following code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

But this will restart the whole `Activity`. I just need to refresh the current `Fragment`.

[image]
[image]

**Edited : Code Added**

**ACTIVITY CLASS**

```
    public class ContactListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        MenuButtonUtil.enableMenuButton(this);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        MyContactsFragment contactListFragment = new MyContactsFragment ();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, contactListFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.show_online) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            String where = "((" + ContactsContentProvider.PHONE_ID + " NOTNULL) AND ((" +
                       ContactsContentProvider.PHONE_ID+ " = 17486 )OR (" +
                       ContactsContentProvider.PHONE_ID+ " = 17494 )))";

            values.put(ContactsContentProvider.STATUS, true);
            this.getContentResolver().update(ContactsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, where, null);

            listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            ((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class MyContactsFragment extends ListFragment{

Button allContactsBtn;
Button neeoContactsBtn;
ListView listView;
CustomAdapterForAllContacts adapterForAllContacts;
CustomAdapterForNeeoContacts adapterForNeeoContacts;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    MenuButtonUtil.enableMenuButton(getActivity());
    adapterForNeeoContacts = new CustomAdapterForNeeoContacts();
    adapterForAllContacts = new CustomAdapterForAllContacts();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactsfragment, container,false);

    allContactsBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.allContactsButton);
    neeoContactsBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.neeoContactsButton);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    // ==================== Neeo Contacts ============================
    neeoContactsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listView.setAdapter(adapterForNeeoContacts);

        }
    });

    // ====================== All Contacts =============================

    allContactsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listView.setAdapter(adapterForAllContacts);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

**Adapter**:

```
private class CustomAdapterForAllContacts extends BaseAdapter {

public CustomAdapterForAllContacts(){

}
    List<Contact> contactsList = getAllContacts();
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return contactsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Contact getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return contactsList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if(view==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup,false);
        }

        TextView contName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        TextView contNumber = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.numberText);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);

        Contact contact = contactsList.get(position);

        String status = contact.getStatus();

        if(contact.getStatus().equals("1")){
            image.setBackgroundResource(com.example.mycontentprovider.R.drawable.person_empty_online);
        }else{
            image.setBackgroundResource(com.example.mycontentprovider.R.drawable.person_empty_offline);
        }

        contName.setText(contact.getName());
        contNumber.setText(contact.getPhoneNumber());
        return view;
    }

    public Contact getContactPosition(int position)
    {
        return contactsList.get(position);
    }
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts(){

        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>(); 

        String URL = "content://com.example.provider.Contacts/contacts";
        Uri baseUri1 = Uri.parse(URL);
        String[] select = {ContactsContentProvider.PHONE_ID, ContactsContentProvider.STATUS};

        String where = "((" + ContactsContentProvider.NEEO_USER + " NOTNULL) AND (" +
                                                   ContactsContentProvider.NEEO_USER+ " = 1 )AND (" +
                                                   ContactsContentProvider.STATUS+ " = 1 ))";

        Cursor cursor =  getActivity().getContentResolver().query(baseUri1, select, where, null, "pid");

        for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Log.w("Filtered IDS",""+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContentProvider.PHONE_ID))+
                    ""+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContentProvider.STATUS)));
        }


        Uri baseUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

        String selection = "((" + 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND (" +
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " != ' ' ))";

        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        Cursor mCursor= getActivity().getContentResolver().query(baseUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

        // Joinging Both Cursors
                CursorJoiner joiner = new CursorJoiner(cursor, new String[] {ContactsContentProvider.PHONE_ID} , mCursor, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID});
                for (CursorJoiner.Result joinerResult : joiner) {
                    Contact cont = new Contact();
                    Log.e("Result", joinerResult.toString());
                    switch (joinerResult) {
                    case LEFT:
                        // handle case where a row in cursorA is unique
                        break;
                    case RIGHT:
                        // handle case where a row in cursorB is unique
                        cont.setID(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)));
                        cont.setName(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                        cont.setPhoneNumber(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                        cont.setStatus("0");
                        contactList.add(cont);
                        break;
                    case BOTH:
                        // handle case where a row with the same key is in both cursors
                        cont.setID(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)));
                        cont.setName(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                        cont.setPhoneNumber(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                        cont.setStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContentProvider.STATUS)));
                        contactList.add(cont);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                mCursor.close();
                cursor.close();
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Used `ListFragment` for that ...

Comment: Then What? Any specific thing about ListFragment regarding refreshing the Fragment.

Comment: and on that adapter `.notifyDataSetChanged()` on Activity `Resume()` or anywhere...it'll update your `ListFragment`...

Comment: Can you show me the code with which you create the `Adapter`? And see my answer for a possible explanation why `notifyDataSetChanged()` does not work in your case. To summarise: you need to change the datasource of the `Adapter`, after that calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` will refresh the `ListView`.

Comment: Try to use Swipe-to-Refresh To Your App. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469040/fragment-refresh/41470603#41470603

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have multiple options to solve this depending on how exactly you implemented your `ListView` and `Adapter`.

1. By calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`
2. By resetting the `Adapter`

---

## Updating with notifyDataSetChanged()

This is the best solution there is, but you need to modify the `List` the `Adapter` is using for this to work. For example if you use an `ArrayAdapter` like this:

```
String[] dataSource = new String[] {
    "A", "B", "C", ...
};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.example, dataSource);
```

As you can see the `String[]` is the dataSource for our `Adapter`. We can modify the array like this, but those changes will not immediately be reflected in the `ListView`:

```
dataSource[0] = "some new String value";
```

Only once we call `notifyDataSetChanged()` will the `ListView` be updated:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

From the [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29):

> **public void notifyDataSetChanged ()**
>
> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

But **DO NOT** confuse `notifyDataSetChanged()` with `notifyDataSetInvalidated()`, because `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` does something completely different and would just mess up your `ListView`.

From the [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetInvalidated%28%29):

> **public void notifyDataSetInvalidated ()**
>
> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data is no longer
>   valid or available. Once invoked this adapter is no longer valid and
>   should not report further data set changes.

---

## Updating by resetting the `Adapter`

This is pretty straight forward. Every time you set a new `Adapter` the `ListView` will update itself. If you cannot use `notifyDataSetChanged()` for some reason then you have to do it like this. Just create a new `Adapter` every time you want to update your `ListView`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.example, newData);
```

And use `setAdapter()` to set it to the `ListView`:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This will always update the `ListView` but there are a few problems with this solution. First and foremost every time you update the `ListView` this way it would scroll back to the top which can be quite annoying when there are frequent updates or when there is a lot of content in the `ListView`.

---

**EDIT:**

There are a few things in your code that are not quite optimal. First and foremost, your `Adapter` should not contain the code to download the contacts. It just doesn't belong there, the only responsibility of an `Adapter` should be that he creates `Views` from a given data source. So first you should move the `getAllContacts()` method outside of the `Adapter`. I suggest you create static helper method for this, I took the liberty of modifying your code accordingly:

```
public class ContactsHelper {

    public static List<Contact> getAllContacts(Context context) {

        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        String URL = "content://com.example.provider.Contacts/contacts";
        Uri baseUri1 = Uri.parse(URL);
        String[] select = {ContactsContentProvider.PHONE_ID, ContactsContentProvider.STATUS};

        String where = "((" + ContactsContentProvider.NEEO_USER + " NOTNULL) AND (" +
                ContactsContentProvider.NEEO_USER + " = 1 )AND (" +
                ContactsContentProvider.STATUS + " = 1 ))";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(baseUri1, select, where, null, "pid");

        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Log.w("Filtered IDS", "" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContentProvider.PHONE_ID)) +
                    "" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContentProvider.STATUS)));
        }

        Uri baseUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

        String selection = "((" +
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND (" +
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " != ' ' ))";

        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        Cursor mCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(baseUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

        // Joinging Both Cursors
        CursorJoiner joiner = new CursorJoiner(cursor, new String[]{ContactsContentProvider.PHONE_ID}, mCursor, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID});
        for (CursorJoiner.Result joinerResult : joiner) {
            Contact cont = new Contact();
            Log.e("Result", joinerResult.toString());
            switch (joinerResult) {
                case LEFT:
                    // handle case where a row in cursorA is unique
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    // handle case where a row in cursorB is unique
                    cont.setID(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)));
                    cont.setName(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                    cont.setPhoneNumber(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                    cont.setStatus("0");
                    contactList.add(cont);
                    break;
                case BOTH:
                    // handle case where a row with the same key is in both cursors
                    cont.setID(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)));
                    cont.setName(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                    cont.setPhoneNumber(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                    cont.setStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContentProvider.STATUS)));
                    contactList.add(cont);
                    break;
            }
        }
        mCursor.close();
        cursor.close();
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

With this code you can get all contacts like this:

```
List<Contact> contacts = ContactsHelper.getAllContacts(getActivity());
```

After this we need to modify your `Adapter` so that `notifyDateSetChanged()` will work:

```
private class CustomAdapterForAllContacts extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<Contact> contactsList;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapterForAllContacts(Context context, List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.contactsList = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contactsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Contact getItem(int position) {
        return contactsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // We expose the List so we can modify it from outside
    public List<Contact> contacts() {
        return this.contactsList;    
    }

    private class SimpleViewHolder {

        private final SparseArray<View> viewArray = new SparseArray<View>();
        private final View convertView;

        public SimpleViewHolder(View convertView) {
            this.convertView = convertView;
        }

        public View get(int id) {
            View view = this.viewArray.get(id, null);
            if(view == null) {
                view = this.convertView.findViewById(id);
                this.viewArray.put(id, view);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        // By implementing the view holder pattern you only need to perform 
        // findViewById() once. This will improve the performance of `ListView`
        // and reduce lag.
        SimpleViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new SimpleViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        viewHolder = (SimpleViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        TextView contName = (TextView) viewHolder.get(R.id.nameText);
        TextView contNumber = (TextView) viewHolder.get(R.id.numberText);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) viewHolder.get(R.id.contact_image);

        Contact contact = getItem(position);

        String status = contact.getStatus();

        if (contact.getStatus().equals("1")) {
            image.setBackgroundResource(com.example.mycontentprovider.R.drawable.person_empty_online);
        } else {
            image.setBackgroundResource(com.example.mycontentprovider.R.drawable.person_empty_offline);
        }

        contName.setText(contact.getName());
        contNumber.setText(contact.getPhoneNumber());
        return view;
    }
}
```

I have changed multiple things in this `Adapter`. First and foremost the `List` of `Contacts` is now final and I added a method `contacts()` to expose the `List` so we can modify the data in the `Adapter` from the outside. I also implemented the view holder pattern so your `ListView` scrolls faster and smoother!

I hope I haven't forgotten anything, but this should be all the changes you need. You can use the new `Adapter` like this:

```
List<Contact> contacts = ContactsHelper.getAllContacts(getActivity());
CustomAdapterForAllContacts adapter = new CustomAdapterForAllContacts(getActivity(), contacts);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If you want to update the `ListView` later on you need to modify the `List` inside the `Adapter` like this:

```
List<Contact> newData = ContactsHelper.getAllContacts(getActivity());
adapter.contacts().clear();
adapter.contacts().addAll(newData);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I hope I could help you and if you have any further questions please feel free to ask!

Comment: Ok, I see. You shouldn't perform the download of the data inside the adapter. Something like that doesn't belong there. The `List` used as data source inside the `Adapter` should normally be final and not handled like you do. I will edit my answer with a few suggestions.

Comment: I have updated my answer! If you have any further questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: I'll take a look, would it bother you if I suggested a different approach to load the data? Do you have to use the `LoaderManager`? What about the `CursorJoiner`?

Comment: I have used CursorJoing and its working as u said. But there is a need where i need to reflect the changes at run time , if a change happens in my actual contact book. that why m using LoaderManager.

Comment: Hello @Xaver Kapeller , can u plz take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863038/avoid-swiperefresh-while-fastscrolling-in-android plz

Comment: Hey @XaverKapeller: Wonderfully illustrated. I am having similar problem, not able to update the listview of a current fragment. It would be great if you can have a quick look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638002/pagerslidingtabstrip-custom-view-using-list-fragment-shows-abrupt-behaviour

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside a Fragment then you can do

```
// code for fetching the data
// ...
// ...
((BaseAdapter) yourlistview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```