# Fragment Refresh

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to refresh a fragment class without detaching from fragment.
I have inserted some data by sqlite but unless I restart my application that change doesn't show up. Please be specific where to add refreshing code and what will be the code.

Comment: Post the relevant code snippets.

Comment: You should add your code to give more context of the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: just solved the issue.Thank you guys for your attention.I am adding my solution here.

Answer (score 1):

```
I haved solved the issue by adding swipe refresh layout. Here is my code :

this is refresh layout :

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



this is refresh listener : 

swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                //do all refreshing tasks  
                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
```